# Multiple ColdFusion websites under same domain overwriting each other's session

Tags: session, cookies, coldfusion

I'm finding that if there are ColdFusion applications hosted under the same domain, your session on one application is lost after you browse to another application. I'm assuming this is because the browser will send the same session cookie to each application, which is validated by the requested ColdFusion application, and is considered invalid if that same ColdFusion application didn't create it. If invalid, it creates new session cookies, when will be considered invalid by any other ColdFusion applications including those you previously had a session with.

Am I correct in this? And if so, is there a work-around? My first thought is to change the name of the cookie used to store the session.

Comment: So you have multiple applications on the same domain. I take it that each one has an `application.cfc` where the name `this.name` is the same?

Comment: Each one has an `application.cfc` but `this.name` isn't necessarily the same. That hadn't even occurred to me as a factor. Does `this.name` play a role in how sessions are handled?

Comment: `this.name` has to be unique.

Comment: This is probably outside the scope of my original question, but would this also work if I had a ColdFusion application hosted under the same domain, but a different port?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way this would happen is if you've got an app name collision. We've got multiple apps on the same domain and they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: @DanBracuk please post as an answer

Comment: Yeah, we have a few apps on one server, but some other ColdFusion apps on a separate webserver. Same domain, different port. I think that's out of the scope of my original question though, but your answer was definitely useful. If you want to post an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as right.